# iOS apps cannot be downloaded or updated

Tags: ios-appstore, itunes-store

I tried to update my apps today, and there appeared a notice said that "iTunes terms & conditions have changed. Before you can proceed you must read & accept the new terms & conditions". I selected OK and agreed the terms and conditions. Then there was another notice said 'download now: ***will now begin to download'. I pressed Ok. Then the first notice about the iTunes terms and conditions appeared again. All the process repeated then and it became an endless loop. I cannot download or update apps.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [widespread issue](http://www.macrumors.com/2012/09/30/widespread-itunes-and-app-store-terms-and-conditions-bug-preventing-new-purchases-and-downloads/) affecting many iOS devices (with the exceptions of international stores). <s>Apple has yet to respond/fix this bug.</s>

**update** It appears that Apple has resolved the issue. You can now download iTunes media normally.